# Issue with defining weight to views in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-layout-weight

I want to make a simple jetpack compose layout, using weights. below is the code

```
Row() {
Column(
    Modifier.weight(1f).background(Blue)){
    Text(text = "Weight = 1", color = Color.White)
}
Column(
    Modifier.weight(2f).background(Yellow)
) {
    Text(text = "Weight = 2")
}
}
```

which will result in a layout like this
[image: Simple row column lauout using weights.]

but what if my inner views are coming from some other Composable function, which is unaware that its going to be a child of a column or a row?

```
Row() {
  // Calling Some composable function here
}
```

In that case i am not able to access the Modifier.weight(..) function, because it thinks that its not in the row or column scope, because it is an independent function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the modifier as parameter in your Composable.

Something like:

```
@Composable
fun myCard(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, name:String){
    Box(modifier){
            Text(name,textAlign = TextAlign.Center,)
    }
}
```

In this way the `myCard` is unaware that its going to be a child of a `Column` or a `Row`.

Then in your implementation you can use:

```
Row(Modifier.padding(16.dp).height(50.dp)) {
    myCard(Modifier.weight(1f).background(Color.Yellow),"Weight = 1")
    myCard(Modifier.weight(2f).background(Color.Red),"Weight = 2")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, its working. but is there any alternative way? if we don't want to send modifier as a parameter? @gabriele-mariotti

Comment: Both the string values "Weight = 1" and "Weight = 2" are left aligned only. 
Could you please explain how can we change their alignment to center or end?

Answer (score 9):

You can prefix `RowScope.` or `ColumnScope.` to your function declaration

```
@Composable
fun RowScope.SomeComposable() {
    // weights should work in here
    Column(Modifier.weight(1f)){ /**/ }

}
```

Comment: works! , this alternative makes me less changes to code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Row(
                modifier = mainRowModifier,
                verticalAlignment = rowCenterVerticallyAlign
            ) {
                Row(
                    verticalAlignment = rowCenterVerticallyAlign,
                    horizontalArrangement = rowContentArrangementCenter,
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(.5f, true).wrapContentHeight()
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "971",
                        maxLines = 1,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                    )
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = resIdDropDownIcon),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = startPaddingDropdownIcon.dp)
                    )
                }

                Divider(
                    color = dividerColor,
                    modifier = dividerModifier
                )

                SimpleTextField(
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(2f),
                    value = "",
                    placeHolder = textFieldPlaceholder,
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Phone,
                    singleLine = true
                )

                Text(
                    text = optionalTextTxt,
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(.5f, true),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall,
                    fontSize = optionalTextFontSize.sp
                )
            }
```

**no weight is issue to main row, then i will assign subrow weight to 0.5 and for textField weight will be 2f and last textview weight is issue to 0.5f**

then Output will be looks like
[image]